# Different Stack Exchange sites have the same logo

Tags: feature-request, favicon

The "[Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)" and "[Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)" Stack Exchange sites have the same exact logo (["CS" in a blue speech balloon](http://cdn.sstatic.net/cs/img/apple-touch-icon.png)). [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) and [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) do as well (["CR" in a blue speech balloon](http://cdn.sstatic.net/crypto/img/apple-touch-icon.png)). This is bad for bookmarks, especially when one identifies them only by their logo. This should be remedied, especially since they cover similar topics.

Comment: How exactly would you recommend they be differentiated?

Comment: Specialize one or both of their logos? This could be as simple as changing the speech balloon's colors for one of them or as complex as having a unique non-balloon symbol that many sites here have (eg: programmers, math, and theoretical computer science sites)

Comment: Only sites which are out of beta get a custom logo like that. It comes with the custom site design. I'm not sure how up-for-it they'd be about changing the color.

Comment: @animuson The problem here is that they are both "CS", changing the color in one could be a very easy solution to this...

Comment: Might I suggest since "Computational Science" is actually scicomp.stackexchange.com it should use SC since no other Beta site is currently using it

Comment: @ajax333221: Read the FAQ.

Comment: I don't really care. If a moderator wants to move this, then fine. Any case, this is a defect.

Comment: This is fine here; don't worry about it. MSO is actually a little broader than what the FAQ suggests, since it's a huge conglomeration of related things, and well, the FAQ shouldn't turn into a 30-minute read.

Comment: @trinithis It would be preferable to ask questions regarding site specific issues on the site's Meta instead of MSO, but since this concerns two sites and it is an issue that needs SE's attention, it's perfectly on topic here (notice that there isn't any close votes, and a fair amount of upvotes, one user saying it's off topic doesn't make it so).

Comment: @TheEstablishment I accept my error, I cleaned all my nonsenses. And I am not ashamed of proving to everybody that I am not perfect :)

Comment: [Cryptography.SE](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) and [Code-Review.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) also have the exact same logo

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/) is now `SC` instead of `CS`.

[image: SC 48]
[image: SC favicon]
Computational Science (a.k.a. **s**cientific **c**omputing)

[image: CS 48]
[image: CS favicon]
**C**omputer **S**cience

[Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) is `Cr` while [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is `CR`. Unfortunately, cryptography's favicon is still [inconsistent with the larger icons](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245/cryptographys-favicon-is-inconsistent-with-larger-icons).

[image: Cr 48]
[image: Cr favicon]
**Cr**yptography

[image: CR 48]
[image: CR favicon]
**C**ode **R**eview

Comment: It might also be worth pointing out that the Computational Science shortname is `scicomp`, which is also consistent with "SC". Naturally, I wondered why the long name was inconsistent, but [found my answer](http://meta.scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/60/why-does-the-url-for-this-stack-exchange-use-scicomp-but-the-title-says-comp) after a few minutes on their Meta.

Comment: Humble suggestion: Make Cryptography `CY` or something.

Comment: @michaelb958 I've never seen cryptography abbreviated `CY`. `Cr` is more logical and common.

Comment: @michaelb958 I know I'm a little late, but what about `EN` (for **en**cryption) instead of `Cr`?

Comment: @ASCIIThenANSI Uh? [cryptography.se] is about cryptography, not just about encryption (like [so] is about programming, not about stack overflows), and it's called *Cryptography*, which doesn't even have `E` and `N` anywhere. It doesn't make any sense to abbreviate “cryptography” based on the word “encryption”.

Comment: Just sayin': the images in this answer do not make a lot of sense, being that they show the current, graduated-site favicons (which are clearly different from each other), instead of the original beta favicons.

Answer (score 5):

This will probably crop up more and more often as SE plods on. As [Ephraim noted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130133/different-stack-exchange-sites-have-the-same-logo#comment356986_130133), Codereview and Cryptography also have the same logo.

Though [out here](https://stackexchange.com/sites), Cryptography is `Cr`, not `CR`(as per favicon). A similar thing with Economics (inconsistency, anyone?), and many other sites.

Stuff I can think of

- [Give one](http://bricks.stackexchange.com) [of them](http://answers.onstartups.com/) [a beta](https://poker.stackexchange.com/) [logo](http://smugmug.stackexchange.com/)!!
- Do some nifty capitalization.
- Add an extra letter, like [Cognitive Sciences](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/) (`CgS`).

Note that these sites are in beta for just <s>a few months</s><sub>^</sub><sup>6-8 weeks</sup>, then they get their own logos.

Comment: @PopularDemand: Oh, right.. The 90 days requirement is just part of the whole picture :/

Comment: +1 great answer, and Love the 6-8 week reference! Also I just realized the difference in CR and Cr on the sites page, however the favicons are both CR.

Comment: @Ephraim that's what I meant when I said 'inconsistency'. Anyway, clarified. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is no longer an issue. With the exception of Computational Science, each of these sites now has a unique logo.

- [image: Computational Science favicon] [Computational Science](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)
- [image: Computer Science favicon] [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/)
- [image: Cryptography favicon] [Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/)
- [image: Code Review favicon] [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)