# Earth Science SE and Spanish SE have the same icon

Tags: feature-request, beta-sites, favicon

The beta sites [Earth Science](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/) and [Spanish](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/) have the same icon.

Icon of Earth Science:

[image: Earth Science icon]

Icon of Spanish:

[image: Spanish icon]

They both have "ES" in a blue speech balloon.

Can they please have different icons?

Comment: One has a Giant S...

Comment: @rene not the smaller icons, those are 100% identical.

Comment: Closely related: [Different Stack Exchange sites have the same logo](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130133/187824)

Comment: I think Earth Science should have [a beta logo](https://www.google.com/search?q=earth+science&site=imghp&tbm=isch "Just for examples") as suggested by [@ManishEARTH](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130145/187824).