# Magento and Martial Arts SE have the same favicon

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, favicon

The favicon of Magento is a blue speech bubble with `MA`, and the favicon of Martial Arts also is a blue speech bubble with `MA`.

Favicon of Magento: [image: Favicon Magento]
Favicon of Martial Arts: [image: Favicon Martial Args]

Note: I'm talking about the **16x16 favicons**, not about the icons on the [site list](https://stackexchange.com/sites), which are different.

Another note: perhaps you are not able to reproduce it (Shadow Wizard [could not](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2747052#2747052)), but then you'll still see it on the site list (screenshot provided by Shadow):

> [image: Site list]

Can they please have different icons?

Comment: It's CAse SENSItive.

Comment: @ShadowWizard The favicons are really identical. Both have "MA" in capital letters.

Comment: Repro'd the same icon (MA) for both favicon and site list on Chrome 39, Win 7 eventhough the favicon link on Magento correctly points to [[Ma](http://cdn.sstatic.net/magento/img/favicon.ico?v=f848b728dab0)].

Comment: Magneto has a lowercase a for me. Chrome on iPad.

Comment: looks like my desktop computer behaves like a mobile device. (both Chrome and IE showing the 32x32 icon which is correct :))

Comment: It’s the same for *Spanish Language* and *Earth Science.*

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Yes, I reported that some time ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230842/229438

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) for two reasons.

One, Magneto graduated and thus has its own favicon now:

[image]
[image]

and other sites that may have this issue like Poker and Politics (both are single words that start with PO) have different favicons:

[image]
[image]

or take some weird cases like Bioinformatics, Bitcoin, and Board & Card Games. Bioinformatics has `BI`. Bitcoin instead has `BC`. You would think Board & Card Games might also have `BC` as other sites like Artificial Intelligence use the first letters of their two words. Nah, Board & Card Games go with `BG`, `G` coming from Games:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Health and History both have H