# Earth Science vs. Spanish Language favicons: now with 0% lowercasing!

Tags: support, status-completed, design, favicon

Coming from here: [Favicon of Earth Science and Spanish are too similar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/285456/favicon-of-earth-science-and-spanish-are-too-similar)

If you thought they were too similar... check this out:

[image]

Seems like now both favicons appear as all-uppercase in the small HNQ list featured in SO's main page.
However they still show different casing in the actual HNQ page, how come?

[image]

I checked the favicon's style in the SO minilist and it shows as `<div class="favicon favicon-spanish" title="Spanish Language Stack Exchange"></div>`. Forcing a no-cache refresh didn't help.

**Is this a permanent change?** Or is it some kind of weird bug?

---

EDIT: after several reloads I managed to get a HNQ list featuring both sites:

[image]

Same favicons, different styles:

[image]

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285456/287315 ? It seems you're just observing the same behavior reported there.

Comment: Not the same at all @WBT This isn't about the icon being too similar. It's identical. It's as if we're using the wrong icon when it's that size.

Comment: I realize that I may have misunderstood what you were saying initially... unfortunately, now that I really understand it, the question is no longer on the HNQ list, so I can't confirm either way. Feel free to ping me if you notice it again.

Comment: @Catija As far as we know, it has been like that [since 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230842/earth-science-se-and-spanish-se-have-the-same-icon#comment758319_230842)

Comment: @Bookends Except that not what the icons generally look like right now. They only appear identical in the right sidebar for HNQs.

Comment: @Catija The small version of the Spanish favicon uses capitalization for readability at that size.  The other question uses "too similar" as understatement for "identical" which is shown in the question itself.

Comment: Spanish.SE started [a meta discussion about changing their favicon](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3051/8656) //cc @SonictheWizardWerehog

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just wanted to let everybody know... Spanish.SE favicon has finally been changed!!! Now it's the cutest lowercase `ñ` in the world, and it's hopefully different enough from any other stack's current favicon -- *especially* Earth Science's ;)

Thanks Catija and our mod fedorqui for sponsoring the [debate over at Spanish.SE Meta](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3051/8656) and for following through with the winning proposal!

Comment: Credit for the actual work goes to our designer, Lisa, and dev, Adam. :D

Comment: @Catija Seems like the favicons in chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=spanish.stackexchange.com are still the old ones, and several of our stack users are asking why. Do you know if this might be a caching problem? Should I open a new question for this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Probably caching but I'll check.

Comment: Confirmed. It changes so infrequently that they're cached for a week. If you still see them after Thursday, let me know.