# Why does the Craft CMS beta site have a different favicon?

Tags: discussion, beta-sites, favicon

I noticed that although it is a BETA site,[Craft CMS](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/) has a different favicon *`it is red instead of the regular blue`*.

[image: browser tab widget with red C icon]

[image: browser tab widget with blue MA icon for Magento Stack Exchange]

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It echoes the [logo for the CMS](https://buildwithcraft.com/):

[image: Craft logo]

Note that the *font* for the letter *C* is matches the logo as well here.

The space of *C* logos is also crowded; we already have [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) (*CR*) and [Cryptography](http://cryptography.stackexchange.com) (*Cr*) already. Shifting to use red here probably made a lot of sense to differentiate. The alternatives, using *just* a *C* on blue or using *Cra* are not distinctive or too crowded.

Comment: @Tim: I don't know. It may have had the icon in private beta too. There is no discussion about the icon on Area51 or in their Meta that gives more context (apart from a [post about resembling a national flag](http://meta.craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/23/current-favicon-looks-like-flag-of-turkey) 1 month after the site opened).

Comment: [Not that there are no sites with isimlar icons](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130133/255554).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: and those have been made distinctive. Thanks for helping me find the *Cr* logo though. :-P