# Health and History sites have the same favicon

Tags: bug, status-completed, favicon

The Health and History sites both have the exact same favicon/logo: (The standard beta one with a single "H" in the middle)

> [image]

In the [past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130133/205970), this has led to logo changes, and it should probably get that here as well. (screenshot is from top bar sites list, but of course it also applies to the icons elsewhere as well)

Comment: They already brought this up on their Meta and it's pending change: [here](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/10/icon-is-identical-to-history) and [here](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/130/voting-for-a-new-icon)

Comment: @animuson having actual icon might take weeks, months, or years if they wait for site graduation as well. Better do something before that. And since it's affecting all sites via the top bar list, it surely belongs here as well. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard That's the plan.

Comment: @animuson: Is there any progress on this?

Comment: [Quite confusing](http://i.stack.imgur.com/psq3D.png) when screening the Hot Network Questions. I'm surprised this hasn't been resolved yet.

Comment: It's time to do something about this. THREE icons have over ten votes in the question linked below, but this continues to cause confusion two years later. Just change Health to He for now if there's no other consensus. There is currently a History HNQ that appears to be about medical issues, whose only answer includes dangerously wrong (but historically appropriate) information; the Health/History confusion makes this more problematic than it needs to be.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This problem is now fixed. Health changed its name to "Medical Sciences" and the icon was changed to match it:

[image: MED icons]

Answer (score 6):

As animuson said in a comment above, this has been brought up on the meta. First, [a post](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/icon-is-identical-to-history) was made letting everyone know about this, and many great ideas for a replacement icon were made. Then [another post](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130/voting-for-a-new-icon) was made to vote on these ideas. So far, two icons are pulling away, but they are both tied with a score of 10. Once one of these is the clear winner, a feature request will be made on Health's meta asking for the new icon.

Comment: Any news on this?

Comment: Rod of Asclepius is a winner now with 17 vs. 12 for the second. Was there a feature request asking to change the icon?