# Banners of questions migrated from per-site metas prior to HTTPS changeover link to the origin site's old URL, resulting in certificate error

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, per-site-meta, ssl

I was browsing through the question [Favicon of Earth Science and Spanish are too similar (exactly the same in HNQ list)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285456/209901) which got migrated from [Earth Science Meta](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com):

> [image]

As you see, the link points to https://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/posts/1563/revisions, that is, to https://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com: `https://meta.<sitename>.stackexchange.com`. If you click on the link it returns a SSL error:

```
$ curl https://meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com/posts/1563/revisions
curl: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'meta.earthscience.stackexchange.com'
```

This is because since [Network-wide HTTPS: It's time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/209901), Meta sites have their URL on a different form, with the `meta` subdomain *after* the site name: `https://<sitename>.meta.stackexchange.com`. On this specific case, the correct path is https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com.

So the bug is that the migration link points to old URL of Meta, instead of the new one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These migration to/from targets have been fixed.

We have fixed it both for the general case highlighted in the question (meta url change due to ssl) as well as the specific pre-4/2014 on MSO case highlighted by Sonic in the other answer here.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a similar problem when it comes to questions migrated out of *this* site to other sites, before the MSO-MSE split.

Prior to April 2014, this site had the URL `meta.stackoverflow.com` and questions about both Stack Overflow and the entire Stack Exchange network were on-topic. However, in April 2014, this site was renamed, with the URL changed to `meta.stackexchange.com` and a new per-site meta was established for Stack Overflow.

Since the URL of this site was `meta.stackoverflow.com` in the past, questions migrated prior to the split have that old URL ([example](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1084/su-tagging-conventions-videocard-vs-graphics-card-general-pc-component-tag)). While the link in the notice is supposed to link to the revision history of the original question (which is supposed to still be visible even after the migration stub is deleted, to comply with CC licensing requirements), clicking on these links leads to a 404 error on Meta Stack Overflow (which, as of April 2014, is a wholly different site from the site it was originally migrated out of). To view the revision histories of these questions, it is necessary to manually modify the URL to `meta.stackexchange.com`.

While this may not seem like a common occurrence, this is indeed so, since in July 2010 a large number of questions were mass-migrated out of this site (because prior to that this site served as the global meta for all Trilogy sites, and older per-site meta questions pertaining to SU and SF were migrated to then-new per-site metas).