# "Puzzling" and "Workplace" Stack Exchange have annoyingly similar icons

Tags: discussion, design

The two SE sites "Puzzling" and "Workplace" have annoyingly similar icons.

[image]

[image]

I have repeatedly gotten confused while looking at the sidebar section with questions from other SE sites due to this.

I also feel like neither of those two icons actually represent the site in question very well, they're just colored swirly thingies without any meaning to them.

Considering that many SE sites do not even *have* an icon and just use a speech bubble with an abbreviation in it (looking at you, Biblical Hermeneutics!), I realize that creating a 32x32px PNG is very hard work and might be too difficult for a mom&pop website like this, but here's my proposal for more clear icons:

- a jigsaw puzzle piece, or a Rubik's cube for the "Puzzling" SE site
- a wrench, or a stylized PC workplace, or maybe a factory, for the "Workplace" SE site.

The communities involved can probably come up with better suggestions than mine, I mostly made them to avoid comments in the style of "yeah, let's see YOU come up with something better". And FWIW, I have actually read a handful of questions on both of these communities.

Addendum: Because many puzzles have fairly abstract titles to intrigue the reader, it is even harder to distinguish between the two at a glance. And while the Moebius strip on the "Puzzling" SE site is definitely a very nice touch, it also isn't really recognizable at standard icon size.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328723/the-network-sites-icons-are-not-expressive

Comment: They *are* different colours - blue/red for Workplace and yellow/orange/green for Puzzling - but I wonder whether colour-blind users might find it hard to tell the difference. I'm not saying *you're* colour-blind, just that you may have raised a legitimate issue.

Comment: also related: https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3711/is-the-puzzling-icon-too-similar-to-ours

Comment: If your goal is to change either of those icons, I think the best approach might be to do so by convincing either (or both) of those sites that it is an actual issue on the metas for those sites.

Comment: Site designs are also a matter of taste and designs have been through a process on the respective meta sites. Don't you think it is a bit weird to propose a design / look and feel for a site without having an user profile there (at least not with this account)? These changes will impact many users every day, not only the occasional confused visitor arriving from the HNQ list.

Comment: I am *not* colorblind (and I have the optometrician results to prove it), so... if even I am impacted by this, I have to wonder how much it actually screws over those people who are. As to convincing the two sites involved - it's not like either of them have done something wrong and there is one party that's in the wrong, it's more of a larger coordination issue. And regarding my lack of interaction with those two communities - well, StackExchange still shows me content from both of them, thus I feel entitled to have an opinion on how they do that.

Comment: I'm not colorblind either and this has bugged me for soooooo long! I'm glad to find out that I'm not the only one.

Comment: Here, at MSE, it's fair to ask (reword your question) if ***any*** site should have a favicon similar to any other sites; otherwise you should visit the child meta of each site, see who was second, and raise the issue there - **after** doing that (if that's your only concern, you're not rewording your question) then it's fair to Appeal here. We are not your first resort for a single site issue of this nature.

Comment: Even the easy option, rotating Puzzling’s icon slightly so that it’s like this  would go a long way. Also, I remember the fact that they’re very similar being discussed before but can’t find the post.

Comment: @Laurel It's [Is the puzzling icon too similar to ours?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3711) (linked above by Rene)

Comment: So what I take from this is that StackExchange does not have something like community managers who could, dunno, chat with some people and figure out a solution, and I (a user who is essentially volunteering their time) should go and fix this obvious UX issue myself? No thank you, and I don't think I'll be giving feedback in the future.

Comment: I was going to meh-vote because they don't look similar to me even though you do have to remember which is which. But a three-colored cube with fine cuts might work well for puzz.se.

Comment: @Taschi SE has dozens of community moderators who can deal with requests like this, but unfortunately, none of them have chosen to reply. I couldn't begin to tell you why. Alternately, you could go to Puzzling Meta or Workplace Meta and discuss this with the moderators there. Nobody here is suggesting that *you personally* need to/have to fix the issue.

Comment: It's only been 14 hours, and they were probably all asleep for most of that.

Comment: @OrangeDog well, that is fair enough. Earlier comments read to me as if stuff like this was out-of-scope for their job.

Answer (score 7):

The branding of each site is "owned" by that site's community, and it is quite an undertaking to get the professional designers' time and the community to all agree on what the complete look & feel should be - it's more than just a 16x16 icon. It's a lot easier these days with the redesign though, than it was originally.

Nobody can jump in and just change these two icons because they're confusingly similar. First you need to get the two communities to individually agree with your proposal (which you do at their respective Meta sites).

It can be done, and it would probably be an improvement. But it needs a leader to dedicate time to championing it, and there are many things that are higher up on staff's priority lists. The communities may also simply not want to, because they invested a lot of time and effort getting something they were happy with in the first place.

Note this issue has already been raised:

- On Workplace: [Is the puzzling icon too similar to ours?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3711/11039)
- On Puzzling: [Puzzling's new favicon is too similar to Workplace's favicon](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4748/9266)

Comment: "*The communities may also simply not want to, because they invested a lot of time and effort getting something they were happy with in the first place.*" - I don't know about Workplace, but the Puzzling community didn't invest anything in that logo; we were just given it on a plate and then told we couldn't get it changed to anything that made more sense for our site/community.

Comment: Do communities actually get to vote on/discuss the site icon?

Answer (score 7):

This has already officially been [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). To quote from [Jon Ericson's answer on Puzzling Meta](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4911/25966), from May 2016:

> ### Short answer
>
> We aren't going to change the logo. While the shapes are similar at a glance, the [treatment](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/67818/13855) and [visual identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corporate_identity#Visual_identity) are completely different. As the number of site designs increase, it will be impossible to avoid logo collisions.

While Jon has left the company since, his answer remains at the moment the company's official stance. (For the longer version of the answer, click through and read it on Puzzling Meta.)